# $f$ analytic in $\Omega$, then partial derivatives are continuous up to 2nd order

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I need to show the following:

"Admit that it's true that "If $f$ is analytic at $\Omega$, then the $f'$ is also analytic in $\Omega$". Now show that if $f$ is analytic in $\Omega$, then the functions $u$ and $v$ (real and imaginary parts of $f$) have continuous partial derivatives up to the 2nd order. Also, show that $u_{xy} = u_{yx}$ and $v_{xy} = v_{yx}$.

I've just studied Cauchy Riemann condition and harmonic functions. I know that when a function is analytic, its $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions, that is:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

The way I interpreted this result, it seems too obvious. If $f$ and $f'$ are analytic, that means their derivatives exists, and so their partial derivatives must be continuous (both for $f$ and $f'$, therefore the order $1$ and $2$ derivatives are continuous). For the second part (proving $u_{xy} = u_{yx}$, ...) isn't it the Schwarz theorem for continuous partial derivatives?

Comment: For the second part, use the cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ and try to relate them to these harmonic formulas you have here.

Comment: @FedePoncio sorry, I can't make a connection, could you be more clear?

Comment: Yeah! Sorry if I wasn't clear: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, then taking partials wrt x on both sides: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ that is $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y}$. But the equations you have there include a $u_{xx}$ and you can substitute that for this new $u_{xy}$, just do the same but wrt $y$ on the other Cauchy-Riemann equation; then do the inverse process and replace on the second of your equations. Is that clear?